# How to Merge Python List containing dictionaries into one final list

Tags: python, arraylist, python-requests, python-3.6

Here are my Lists:

```
prices = [
    {'price': '19,294'}, {'price': '20,365'}, {'price': '21,437'},
    {'price': '22,628'}, {'price': '25,963'}, {'price': '26,439'},
    {'price': '28,821'}, {'price': '29,417'}, {'price': '26,320'},
    {'price': '26,797'}, {'price': '29,179'}, {'price': '29,774'},
    {'price': '46,686'}, {'price': '47,162'}, {'price': '51,807'},
    {'price': '52,402'}]

occupancy = [
    {'occupancy': 2}, {'occupancy': 2}, {'occupancy': 2},
    {'occupancy': 2}, {'occupancy': 3}, {'occupancy': 3},
    {'occupancy': 3}, {'occupancy': 3}, {'occupancy': 4},
    {'occupancy': 4}, {'occupancy': 4}, {'occupancy': 4},
    {'occupancy': '6'}, {'occupancy': '6'}, {'occupancy': '6'},
    {'occupancy': '6'}]
```

Expected results:

```
results = [
    {'price': '19,294','occupancy': 2},
    {'price': '20,365','occupancy': 2},
    {'price': '52,402','occupancy': '6'}, .....]
```

They are of the same len() and of the same order/range()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `zip` with a list comprehension

**Ex:**

```
prices = [{'price': '19,294'}, {'price': '20,365'}, {'price': '21,437'}, {'price': '22,628'}, {'price': '25,963'}, {'price': '26,439'}, {'price': '28,821'}, {'price': '29,417'}, {
    'price': '26,320'}, {'price': '26,797'}, {'price': '29,179'}, {'price': '29,774'}, {'price': '46,686'}, {'price': '47,162'}, {'price': '51,807'}, {'price': '52,402'}]

occupancy = [{'occupancy': 2}, {'occupancy': 2}, {'occupancy': 2}, {'occupancy': 2}, {'occupancy': 3}, {'occupancy': 3}, {'occupancy': 3}, {'occupancy': 3}, {
    'occupancy': 4}, {'occupancy': 4}, {'occupancy': 4}, {'occupancy': 4}, {'occupancy': '6'}, {'occupancy': '6'}, {'occupancy': '6'}, {'occupancy': '6'}]

result = [{**m, **n} for m, n in zip(prices, occupancy)]
```

**Output:**

```
[{'occupancy': 2, 'price': '19,294'},
 {'occupancy': 2, 'price': '20,365'},
 {'occupancy': 2, 'price': '21,437'},
 {'occupancy': 2, 'price': '22,628'},
 {'occupancy': 3, 'price': '25,963'},
 {'occupancy': 3, 'price': '26,439'},
 {'occupancy': 3, 'price': '28,821'},
 {'occupancy': 3, 'price': '29,417'},
 {'occupancy': 4, 'price': '26,320'},
 {'occupancy': 4, 'price': '26,797'},
 {'occupancy': 4, 'price': '29,179'},
 {'occupancy': 4, 'price': '29,774'},
 {'occupancy': '6', 'price': '46,686'},
 {'occupancy': '6', 'price': '47,162'},
 {'occupancy': '6', 'price': '51,807'},
 {'occupancy': '6', 'price': '52,402'}]
```

Comment: thank you. this works like a charm, maybe I need to read about the Zip